# More complex attribute parameter

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I want to use of  `System.Attribute` to create some metadata for my class.
what I need is to use compiler advantages in getting names instead of using `string`s. but my approach can not be done because attibutes does not accept complex parameter like I wrote here:

```
Public Class Foo
   Public Property Id as Integer
   <Attribute(AttributeInputA.Create(of Bar)(Function(item) item.Name))>
   Public Property Name as String
End Class 
Public Class Bar
    Public Property Name as String
End Class
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property Or
                   AttributeTargets.Field,
                   AllowMultiple:=True)>
Public Class Attribute
   Public Sub New(attibuteInputA as AttributeInputA)
   End Sub
End Class
Public Class AttributeInputA
    Public Share Function Create(Of T)(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of Object , T)) AS AttributeInputA
    End Function
End Class
```

What I want to know is that is there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize the string into anything you want.  In this case you would use the code as the source for CodeDom (requires compiler be available) or Reflection.Emit (which doesn’t but needs to IL).

either way, seems like a lot of trouble for not to much reward.  I would write specific case that I needed and then use a dictionary lookup or class to find it.

Comment: actually I don't want use strings, I want the compiler checks some prerequisites for me and complain on some error that I may occur in compile time

Comment: You have no choice but to use a string for the attribute, what that string represents is up to you.